# How to return to the starting activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm programming a simple game, and after playing, the player sees a score-screen, in which the points are written. Now, I want the player to have a "Return to main screen" button that brings him to the main activity, which is `StartActivity`.

I tried the following code (see below), but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ScoreActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById (R.id.startbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ScoreActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
        Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: you mean you want to clear all activities from the stack and restart the app from StartActity.class ?

Comment: you have to use startActivityForResult() insted of startActivity()...

Comment: yes, that's what i ment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following `flags` when calling `intent`

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

so this will remove previous back stack i e now you use this .

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(ScoreActivity.this, StartActivity.class)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }
```

Now you are at starting activity and when press back then app exits

Answer (score 0):

Create  one method as follow :

```
public void startIntentClearingStack(Context context, Intent in) {
        in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
        context.startActivity(in);
    }
```

call this method first & then call startActivity() for `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way working like charm

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ScoreActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

Comment: when i try that, eclipse shows an error at activity.startActivity(mainIntent);

Comment: you need to put android-support.jar to your libs folder

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: Ok got your problem remove activity

Comment: so i need to remove this activity and then...?